# Best way of passing values between UI and Code modules in Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin

I am in the process of creating a cross platform app in Xamarin for Android and IOS.
The app needs to return the location of the device (Longitutue, Latitude, first line of address)
It also needs to read specific data from Mifare Ultralight Fobs.
When presented with an 'Admin Fob' the app will switch to Write Mode allowing the user to program Fobs for other users.
I have solved the basic issues in that I can get the address details and read / write data to a Fob.

As Xamarin is constantly evolving I was wanting to know what the best approach is to passing information back and forth between the UI and the underling code modules.

There seems to be
1) use static variables
2) Dependency Injection
3) Messaging Centre

I am also very new to Xamarin.

Comment: I recommend using the [MVVM pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/enterprise-application-patterns/mvvm). But this question seems to broad to be answered clearly, as all approaches have upsides and downsides and there is not 1 clear *best* solution for anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static Variables are not a good choice for UI values unless you know what you're doing.

The simplest approach is like @MindSwipe said the MVVM pattern. Create a simple ViewModel, set it as BindingContext and use Binding in XAML. Its mostly the same as WPF, so you can use many guides for WPF which works also for Xamarin.

Here is a simple example:

```
public class MyViewPage : ContentPage
{
  MyVieModel ViewModel = null;
  public MyViewPage(){
    this.BindingContext = ViewModel = new MyViewModel();
  }
}
```

The ViewModel:

```
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
 {
   private int _Counter = 0;
   public int Counter
   {
     get { return _Counter; }
     set
     {
       _Counter = value;
       OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Counter));
     }
   }
 }
```

and on XAML just simple Binding:

```
<Label Text="{Binding Counter}" />
```

Binding works with Two-Way Binding by default, so when you set the Counter, the UI is updated imidiately.

Comment: How  do I communicate with the above view model example from the Android project?

Comment: if you want to communicate from your **Xamarin.Forms** Project to your **Xamarin.Android** (or iOS or UWP) Project, you need to use the [DependencyService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction)